# Nested getJson() & PHP PDO

Tags: javascript, getjson

I have looked at other questions and answers regarding this, but can't seem to wrap my head around it...

I have a javascript function:

```
function getStates(theDiv){
var stateGroupData;
var stateData;

var theGHtml = "";

var theHtml = "<h4>MyPage</h4>";
theHtml = theHtml+"<h5>select a state...</h5>";

$.getJSON("getStateGroups.php", function(data) {
    stateGroupData = data;
    theHtml = theHtml+"<ul>";

    $.each(stateGroupData, function(i,jsonData) {
        theHtml = theHtml+"<li><a href='#"+jsonData.groupName+"'>"+jsonData.groupID+"</a></li><br/>";

        var theSQL = "getStates.php?gid="+jsonData.groupName;

        theGHtml = theGHtml+"<div id='"+jsonData.groupName+"'>";

        $.getJSON(theSQL, function(data2) {   
            stateData = data2;

            $.each(stateData, function(i,jsonData2) {
                                       alert(jsonData2.stateName);
                theGHtml = theGHtml+"<span sname='"+jsonData2.stateName+"' lat='"+jsonData2.centerLat+"' lon='"+jsonData2.centerLon+"' zom='"+jsonData2.zoom+"'>"+jsonData2.stateName+"</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            });

        });
        theGHtml = theGHtml+"</div>";

    });

    theHtml = theHtml+"</ul>";
});

theDiv.html = theHtml+theGHtml;
}
```

The second (ie. nested) getJson does not return any thing... Both PHP files just use PDO to request data from the SAME table. I run the SQL in each file without any issues, so the SQL seems OK.

Is this an sync v. async issue with the calls to getJson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this an sync v. async issue with
>   the calls to getJson?

Probably. I think this is your problem:

```
stateData = data2;
```

Try changing that to:

```
var stateData = data2;
```

The first one sets a global variable. The second one sets a variable that is local to that function.

You might benefit from refactoring this whole process such that you only need to make one AJAX call. It looked like you were pulling individual people associated with a group. You'd get better performance on the server from a single script which can, when needed, return people associated with the group but otherwise just returns the group.

Remember, every AJAX call is another hit to your server.

Comment: +1 Remove globals is always a good tip! The AJAX callbacks are not guaranteed to run in the order you called them. And yeah, those inner AJAX calls are begging to be refactored into a single SQL call on the server, if you can control it. I don't think  this is a async/sync issue.

Comment: So, let me get this right...maybe change the first getJson/SQL call to return all my data, so I don't make repeated calls?

Comment: That is the suggestion, doesn't address the issue at hand but will make your server very happy! I would still like to find out what's not working, if I were you. Did you try using variables that are local to the callbacks? Did you debug it with firebug to make sure the XHR calls are passing the right parameters and returning the correct JSON?

Comment: I did have local variables at first, which behaved the same way. I have used Firebug, but don't see any errors returned at any point.

Comment: Yes, if you do that, then it'll make your inner AJAX issues go away. Synchronous AJAX calls is not the way to go. Frankly, it would just be better to make it so that the first call returns what you're looking for. It's not hard to put a conditional case in the web service supporting the call to make it embed the users' information if so requested.